# Where can I find a (C++ specific) unlimited integer class that works well with boost::rational?

Tags: boost, integer, rational-number, multiprecision

I want to work with rational numbers whose numerator and denominator can go well above the limit of even long long int's, and boost::rational is a nice class that was specifically designed for unlimited integer types. But when I look up what unlimited integer types exist for C++, the only one that's ever recommended is GMP, which was designed for C and hence has annoying memory management things to deal with. Does there exist a C++ (not C) library that contains an unlimited integer type that works well with boost::rational?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24136288/85371

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost has the rational type that you are looking for, only not as part of Boost Rational: it's in Boost Multiprecision: [`cpp_rational`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/rational/cpp_rational.html)